# Is it necessary to lock simultaneous SQLite access for SELECT statements?

Tags: ios, multithreading, sqlite

I am using FMDB to access the standard iOS internal SQLite database, with one db connection shared among multiple threads.

To make it thread safe I'm locking access to the db to one block of code at a time. All works well, although the access to the db is now a bit of a bottleneck, obviously.

My question is: Can I ease this up a bit by allowing simultaneous queries from multiple threads, as long as they are all readonly SELECT statements?

I can't find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the same connection to execute multiple queries at the same time.

However, for purely read-only accesses, you can use multiple connections.

Comment: You can allow multiple threads to use the same connection by configuring `SQLITE_THREADSAFE`, but this is implemented with a simple mutex around all calls, so you would not get any concurrency.

Comment: I only just now got around to test this in my code, hence the late acception, but this was exactly the answer I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can have one `FMDatabase` object for each thread. You might have to write code to test for genuine busy conditions and handle them properly. For example set `busyRetryTimeout` appropriate for your situation (e.g. how long do you want it to retry in contention situations). Also gracefully handle if the timeout expires and your database query fails.

Clearly, using a shared `FMDatabaseQueue` is the easiest way to do database interactions from multiple threads. See the [Using FMDatabaseQueue and Thread Safety](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/blob/master/README.markdown) section of the FMDB `README`.

Comment: The documentation is not clear, but I think FMDatabaseQueue will not execute multiple read-only queries simultaneously. Right?

Comment: @Stefan Correct. `FMDatabaseQueue` is a "serial" queue, meaning that it ensures that queries are not conducted concurrently. It's the safest and easiest way to interact with a database from multiple queues. But if you want them to potentially operate concurrently, then create separate `FMDatabase` objects for the different queues, but just make sure you handle "database busy" timeouts gracefully.